# how to embed lat and longitude in google places url

Tags: java, url, google-places-api

I am using GenericUrl class to embed my latitude and longitude in url. How do I use `GenericUrl`?

Here are some of the places that use `GenericUrl`:

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/class-use/GenericUrl.html

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation at [`GenericURL`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/GenericUrl.html), it seems this class is intend for decoding a URL and not constructing a new one.  You will need to use a different mechanism to construct a Google Places URL.